# htmx isn't call in meta widgets

Tags: django, htmx

I'm trying to validate a field in a crispy form in Django using htmx:

forms.py

```
class FooForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    id = forms.CharField( label='Id', disabled="true")
    # WORKING
    local_amount = forms.DecimalField( label='Local Amount', required=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                        'type': 'number',  # Use 'number' type for numeric input
                                        'hx-get': reverse_lazy('check_amount'),
                                        'hx-trigger': 'change',  # Trigger the request when the value changes
                                    }) )

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['id','local_amount',.....]
        # NOT WORKING IN THIS WAY
        widgets = { 'local_amount' : forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                        'type': 'number',  # Use 'number' type for numeric input
                                        'hx-get': reverse_lazy('check_amount'),
                                        'hx-trigger': 'change', 
                                    })
                 }
```

models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField( primary_key=True)
    local_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    
 
    def __str__( self):
        return str(self.id )
```

The htmx call is working in the first way but not on the second way?

Comment: Can you update the question with the models and validating view.